# can not execute arc diff, can not comprehend error

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I'm completely new to arc diff. And I cannot find this error code or the solution anywhere. Has anyone else faced it? Have I configured arc wrong? Let me know if more info is required.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with php, I had an older version. Even though arcanist site said it supported the version I had, i couldn't execute the arc diff command, works fine after getting the latest PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update `libphutil` or `arcanist`? - There is an issue with arcanist running on windows: https://secure.phabricator.com/T10936

You need to rollback the repos to:

- arcanist :  `737f5c0`
- libphutil : `5d47fb1`